# Random sort array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, random

I am trying to shuffle the original deck of cards, then subtract 2 cards from the shuffled deck, being player one's cards. Then before I move to player 2, I would like to shuffle the cards again, whose length should be at 50(52-2). The second player I will repeat the process(50-2).

Notice the order of the third console log array before uncommenting the fourth console log and freshDeck__01 in the JavaScript. The order is good before uncommenting. I want that order, and then to shuffle.

```js
 let playerone = document.querySelector(".dealItP1");
 let playertwo = document.querySelector(".dealItP2");
 let playerthree = document.querySelector(".dealItP3");
 let playerfour = document.querySelector(".dealItP4");

 let deck = ["2 Club","2 Spade","2 Diamond","2 Heart","3 Club","3 Spade","3 Diamond","3 Heart","4 Club","4 Spade","4 Diamond","4 Heart","5 Club","5 Spade","5 Diamond","5 Heart","6 Club","6 Spade","6 Diamond","6 Heart","7 Club","7 Spade","7 Diamond","7 Heart","8 Club","8 Spade","8 Diamond","8 Heart","9 Club","9 Spade","9 Diamond","9 Heart","10 Club","10 Spade","10 Diamond","10 Heart","Jack Club","Jack Spade","Jack Diamond","Jack Heart","Queen Club","Queen Spade","Queen Diamond","Queen Heart","King Club","King Spade","King Diamond","King Heart","Ace Club","Ace Spade","Ace Diamond","Ace Heart"];

let originaldeck = [...deck];
 
 
 function dealIt(){
  
  
 

  
 function shuffle(deck) {
  var currentIndex = deck.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    
    temporaryValue = deck[currentIndex];
    deck[currentIndex] = deck[randomIndex];
    deck[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return deck;
}
  
  
  
  
  
  


var arr = deck;     

let freshDeck_00 = shuffle(arr); //length = 52 *Working* shuffled//
  
  
  
let p1Deal = freshDeck_00.filter(function(value, index, arr){return index < 2;}); //length=2 *Working* PlayerOne delt cards//
  
 
 
  let loadedDeck_00 = freshDeck_00.filter(x => !p1Deal.includes(x)).concat(p1Deal.filter(x => !freshDeck_00.includes(x)));   
  //length = 50 *Working* Symmetrical Difference between p1Deal and freshdeck_00 set to loadedDeck_00 ready to be shuffled again//
  
  
  playerone.innerHTML= p1Deal;
  
 // let freshDeck_01 = shuffle(loadedDeck_00);// 
  
 //*IMPORTANT* WORKING UP TO THIS POINT WITH THE THRE CONSOLE LOGS, BUT WHEN UNCOMMENTING FRESHDECK_01 AND FORTH CONSOLE LOG, NOTICE THE DIFFERENCE IN ORDER OF LOADEDDECK__00(THIRD CONSOLE LOG)//
  
  
  console.log(freshDeck_00);
  console.log(p1Deal);
  console.log(loadedDeck_00);
  //console.log(freshDeck_01);//
  
 
  
 }
```

```css
.main{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px solid green;
 height: 1000px;
 width: 1000px;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: black;
 
 
}
.title{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10%;
 left: 50%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: .2;
 font-family: coniferous, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 300;
}
.P1{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 left: 45%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: .5;
 font-family: coniferous, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: red;
}
.P2{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 left: 10%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: .5;
 font-family: coniferous, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: red;
}
.P3{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 60%;
 left: 45%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: .5;
 font-family: coniferous, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: red;
}
.P4{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px green solid;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 left: 80%;
 background-color: green;
 opacity: .5;
 font-family: coniferous, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="pokerTryOne.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
 
 <div class="main">
 
 <header><h1 class="title"><button onClick="dealIt()">Click Button to Deal</button></h1></header>
   <div class="P1"><p>Pot:</p><div class="dealItP1"></div></div>
   <div class="P2"><p>Pot:</p><div class="dealItP2"></div></div>
   <div class="P3"><p>Pot:</p><div class="dealItP3"></div></div>
   <div class="P4"><p>Pot:</p><div class="dealItP4"></div></div>
  <div class="dealBet"></div>
  <div class="flopIt"></div>
  <div class="flopBet"></div>
  <div class="turnIt"></div>
  <div class="turnBet"></div>
  <div class="riverIt"></div>
  <div class="riverBet"></div> 
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pokerTryOne.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`Array#sort` does not create a new array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like to randomize freshdeck_01 into a new array and set that value equal to freshdeck_01_fresh

Comment: Rather than uploading `.zip`s, consider just putting the code into your question - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: @MathewStratton : check out my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array/56749849#56749849) for array shuffling. It implements [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) which is the [fastest](https://jsperf.com/array-shuffle-mine/1) eligible method of array shuffling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I wanted to reassign freshdeck_01 by randomizing it again I
>   receive the same array as before.

**No you do not receive an array that is ordered the same way as before.**

The issue here is that [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts the array *in-place*. This means that you are shuffling your original array `freshdeck_01` and then assigning a reference to that very same (now shuffled) array to another variable `freshdeck_01_fresh`. If you actually inspect your array before running your shuffling function, you will see that the order gets changed:

```
let deck = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
console.log(deck);
deck.sort(function(a, b){return 0.5 - Math.random()});
console.log(deck);
```

If you need to keep a copy of your unshuffled array, you can use a decomposing assignment `[...x]` to do that. Simple assignment would not work, as it would only create a reference to the same array.

```
let deck = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
let copyOfOrigDeck = [...deck];
let notASeparateCopy = deck;

console.log(deck);
deck.sort(function(a, b){return 0.5 - Math.random()});
console.log('unshuffled: ' + copyOfOrigDeck);
console.log('shuffled: ' + deck);
console.log('notASeparateCopy: ' + notASeparateCopy);
```

All that being said, there are probably better ways to shuffle array elements than your approach. I am no expert in that field, so I will leave that research up to you.

Comment: Array shuffling by `sort()` method **does not** produce *really* random output. [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) algorithm is the [fastest](https://jsperf.com/array-shuffle-mine/1) eligible method. You may check out my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array/56749849#56749849) in that regard which is nearly as compact as yours, while producing valid random shuffle.

Comment: Well, my intention was to answer the original question and point the OP at his misunderstanding of `sort` rather than to provide a viable shuffling algorithm. The OP has edited the question since and now asks something completely different. BTW, I just stumbled at this nice visualisation tool which also provides a very simple implementation of Fisher-Yates: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/compare.html

Answer (score 0):

```
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
// Returns a random value from a list.
const sampleFromList = list => list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)]

const shuffle = (
  list,
  // Creates an array with every index of the original list.
  availableIndexes = [...list].map((n, i) => i),
  shuffledList = [],
) => {
  // Asks for a random index from the whitelist of available indexes.
  const availableIndex = sampleFromList(availableIndexes)

  // Adds the value of what's in the original list in the random whitelisted index.
  shuffledList = [...shuffledList, list[availableIndex]]
  // Filters out the used index, so is not used again.
  availableIndexes = availableIndexes.filter(n => n !== availableIndex)

  return (
    // If there are available indexes, use a recursive function to continue shuffling. Otherwise return the shuffled list.
    availableIndexes.length
        ? shuffle(list, availableIndexes, shuffledList)
        : shuffledList
  )
}

console.log(shuffle(numbers))
```

Comment: Sorry friend! I did it in a hurry, I added comments I hope you find helpful. Let me know if you need clarification somewhere in the code.